# Are there any electric ultralight aircraft?

Tags: faa-regulations, electric-engine, ultralight

Are there any electric, FAR part 103 aircraft?

FAR part 103 aircraft are unique in that [they don't need a license to fly](http://www.usua.org/faq.htm#Q9).

Comment: Please don't confuse something that doesn't need a license with something that doesn't need training, because nothing is further from the truth. Unfortunately there are many people no longer around with the same attitude. If you are really serious about flying, renting a 150 and getting your PPL or even SPL isn't a bad thing.

Comment: Note that not everyone can make the requirements for a medical certificate; flying under the more restrictive part 103 limitations on vehicle specs and operating rules greatly reduces the risk to other people of your making a mistake or having a medical problem in flight. That said, GET SUITABLE TRAINING BEFORE FLYING SOLO -- I intend to!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[ElectraFlyer](http://www.electraflyer.com) offers a Part 103 legal trike, and at least as of two years ago, had a flying prototype of a more conventional designed single-seat Part 103 legal ultralight.

Realistically, given the weights of engines and batteries compared to the weights of the Rotax or similar engines usually used on ultralights, it's possible to turn many Part 103 designs into electric power, provided you're willing to do the engineering work yourself. For a fairly extreme example, see [Dale Kramer's eLazair](http://lazairinfo.com/electric-lazair/), a twin electric motor conversion of the Lazair ultralight that retains its Part 103 status.